# How two separate vlans communicate

Tags: cisco, vlan, acl

i have 4 vlans in my network.VLAN 10,VLAN 20,VLAN 30 and VLAN 40. I need Vlan 10 should communicate with vlan 20 but not with others(VLAN 30 and 40).VLAN 30 should communicate with VLAN 40 but not with ohers(VLAN 10 AND 20). How can i do it through switch and router commands?

Comment: Generally, you need to apply access control lists on the router interfaces.  What are the model of routers and switches?

Comment: cisco switch and router. Please tell me general configuration.Give me an example

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post your current router configuration.  Is this a school assignment?

Comment: Current switch is Cisco catalyst 3950 and Router is Cisco 3900. VLAN 10 Is in range 192.168.1.X, VLAN 20 is 10.10.20.X, VLAN 30 is 10.10.30.X,  VLAN 40 is 10.10.40.X.

Comment: Still need the router config, so we can show you how to apply the access lists.

Comment: By "config", Ron means if you can edit your question to include the sanitized output of a `show run` command on the devices in question.

Comment: You have not included enough information to help you. Please include, at the very least, your network device models and (sanitized) configurations. You can consult the [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499).

Answer (score 3):

To start with, separate VLANs are separate layer-2 segments - they can't communicate directly. To enable communication, a router is required. This router can be an external router (with dedicated untagged links or a VLAN trunk), or - preferably - a layer-3 core switch that the traffic needs to pass anyway.

With a layer-3 switch, the usual default is to route everything. You need to set up ACLs to limit the routing/communications to what you require and apply the ACLs to either the inbound ports or the VLANs.